# Adding constant to array.count Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a table that rowspan should equal the number of items in the array. The code snippet is this:

```
<% tasks.each do |task|%>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="<%= task.subtasks.count%>"><strong><%=task.name%></strong>
     <% tasks.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
       <td><%= subtask.name %></td>
   </td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

This code essentially does what I want, HOWEVER, it leaves out the last element of the task.subtasks and makes that element it's own row. Is there a way to +1 the count for the array to be all inclusive?

Comment: Can you add screenshot?

Comment: Are you missing a closing `end` for your inner loop?

Comment: Good catch @AnthonyE

Comment: I figured it out. Much like Java or C# arrays I just did task.subtasks.count+1 to fix the issue. I believe the issue would be that the task is already on 1 when the subtask starts it's iteration at 0. So plus one alleviates that issue.